# GridView with customs view

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

I don't know if it is possible, but actually I wouldn't see why not.

Can we do a grid view not just with ImageView but with a custom view.

I am trying to make a grid view of a view composed of an ImageView and a TextView.

I know that everything happens in my Adapter getView's function but I can't figure out how to do it.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View cases = findViewById(R.id.fileUnitLayout);

    if (convertView == null) {
       convertView = new View(mContext);
    } else {
       cases = convertView;
    }

       return cases;
    }
```

My view has an id of R.id.fileUnitLayout. Let's say my inner TextView has an id of A and my inner ImageView has an id of B. How can I fill them ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not need to override getView to accomplish this, necessarily.  `GridView` is an `AdapterView` so you can provide an adapter that will display what you want via [setAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#setAdapter%28android.widget.ListAdapter%29)

You could, for example, use [SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html) to provide an xml file that is used for each grid view item.

Comment: But we need to overrides getView method in the adapter class. The SimpleAdapter can only be used for static data.Am I right?